# Does question migration occur very rarely or are most of them closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, migration

I recently worked with the Stack Exchange datadump and I found that less than 1% of questions are migrated (according to the data). Is this true, does question migration occur only very rarely on Stack Exchange websites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's true; only high-quality question are supposed to be migrated; migrations are relatively rare.

Most off-topic questions that might be on-topic on another Stack Exchange site are just not worth the effort. Most migrations involve moderators on two sites (one to initiate the migration and another on the target site to verify that the question is indeed worth transferring).

Generally speaking, most people that write high-quality questions have already done their homework and picked the right site to ask their question on before posting.

Comment: Okay! Thanks!! sangeeta